# Sorbet setup results in tc complaining about rbi file?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Following the setup instructions [here](https://sorbet.org/docs/adopting) I get the following when I eventually run `bundle exec srb tc`

```
sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed/lib/rspec-core/all/rspec-core.rbi:1638: Unable to resolve constant RecursiveConstMethods https://srb.help/5002
    1638 |  extend RSpec::Support::RecursiveConstMethods
```

Why does sorbet complain about `rbi` files that it itself created? Did I miss a step where I have to tell it to ignore rbi files or something?

My gemfile looks like

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# Specify your gem's dependencies in testgem.gemspec
gemspec

gem 'sorbet', :group => :development
gem 'sorbet-runtime'
```

Comment: What versions of ruby, rspec & sorbet are you using? I submitted a PR to slim down the sorbet-typed file, does it resolve your issue? https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet-typed/pull/385

Comment: After that PR was merged it worked! Thanks a ton!